# Is there a way to bit reverse a 32-bit binary integer in ARM Assembly language without using carry flags or RRX?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

In the normal way, we would have used LSLS, #1 instruction on the 32-bit binary number where the MSB will be kept in the carry and use RRX to push it back into another register in order to reverse the bits, and we will do this for 32 times.

But if we are not allowed to RRX specifically and any carry bits,  is there another way to reverse the bits?

Comment: Of course. Can you do it in C? That does not have rotate or carry either. Hint: you can mask off a bit before it would go into the carry.

Comment: If your CPU has a sufficiently new microarchitecture, it might have the `rbit` instruction which does exactly that.

Comment: rotate is not required to reverse bits BTW, just one easy way to make a loop to solve the problem.

Comment: But what if I must do it solely in ARM assembly language without C

Answer (score 3):

You've tagged cortex m3 which is the Arm V7-m architecture, and cortex a8 which is the Arm V7-a architecture, both of these have the `rbit` instruction which reverses bits in a 32 bit register.